# A single MFC/Win32 control seems to be making my whole desktop repaint

Tags: c++, mfc, winapi

I have a custom control, which owns an edit box and moves it around, etc. The edit-box is typically modified with a wodge of code like this:

```
edit.MoveWindow( &rc );
edit.SetWindowText( text );
edit.SetLimitText( N );
edit.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
edit.SetFocus();
edit.SetSel(0, CB_ERR);
```

RECT rc is in coordinates local to the custom control, edit is created with the custom control as parent. I'm not even sure this *is* definitely the problem, but when triggering this code sometimes it is nice and smooth, other times my entire desktop appears to flicker like it's being redrawn. I can't see I'm explicitly calling Invalidate(Rect) anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you comment out that code in your application, does the desktop still flicker?

Comment: 'wodge' is a cool word, I'm going to try to work that into my everyday vocabulary :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be any of the code that you are showing us.  A whole desktop flash is nearly always somewhere in your code that is calling `InvalidateRect(NULL,...)` so keep digging.

Several of these calls will result in messages being sent to the parent window of the edit, most likely the InvalidateRect is happening while handling that message.

If I was a betting man, I'd bet on the SetFocus() call as the one that's triggering the repaint.